# Unable to open file for profiling

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I am running a C/C++ program which is trying to open a file kept on disk. If I run the program without cachegrind it runs perfectly. But if I run the program with cachegrind I get the following error. Can someone please help me correct the error:

```
==25989== Cachegrind, a cache and branch-prediction profiler
==25989== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote et al.
==25989== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25989== Command: ./executionFile --main-stacksize=1000000000000
==25989== 
--25989-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the LL simulation.
--25989-- warning: pretending that LL cache has associativity 30 instead of actual 20
==25989== 
==25989== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==25989==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
==25989==    at 0x409D01: MyFile::open(char const*, bool) (MyFile.cpp:117)
==25989==    by 0x4042C5: main (executionFile.cpp:193)
==25989==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==25989==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==25989==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==25989==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==25989==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==25989== 
==25989== I   refs:      1,642,435
==25989== I1  misses:        1,695
==25989== LLi misses:        1,655
==25989== I1  miss rate:      0.10%
==25989== LLi miss rate:      0.10%
==25989== 
==25989== D   refs:        542,393  (404,546 rd   + 137,847 wr)
==25989== D1  misses:       13,170  ( 11,239 rd   +   1,931 wr)
==25989== LLd misses:        7,961  (  6,510 rd   +   1,451 wr)
==25989== D1  miss rate:       2.4% (    2.7%     +     1.4%  )
==25989== LLd miss rate:       1.4% (    1.6%     +     1.0%  )
==25989== 
==25989== LL refs:          14,865  ( 12,934 rd   +   1,931 wr)
==25989== LL misses:         9,616  (  8,165 rd   +   1,451 wr)
==25989== LL miss rate:        0.4% (    0.3%     +     1.0%  )
```

I need to do profiling in order to find out the number of cache misses.
Can someone please help me correct the error

EDIT:
I am trying to open my file using:

```
   int file=::open(name_of_my_File,readOnly?O_RDONLY:O_RDWR);
```

Comment: Well, looking at the error it looks like open tried to dereference -1 as a `char *` which obviously isnt correct-- are you supposed to give a command line arg?. You need to show us the code.

Comment: @ScottyBauer I have included in the question..the code which is trying to open the file. I would like to show the entire code but I can not as the code is very big